# Checking for np.nan inside function that is applied to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_i2b2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],
                        'DIAGNOSIS_CODES':["338.29; 353.6; 355.9; 722.6; 724.2; E43",
                               "278.00; 300.00; 305.1; 353.6",
                               "E66.9; F32.9; F41.9; J96.10; S06",
                               np.nan]})


def diag_TBI(my_str):
    if my_str.isna():
        return np.nan
    else:
        return 1



df_i2b2['TBI_var'] = df_i2b2['DIAGNOSIS_CODES'].apply(diag_TBI)
df_i2b2['TBI_var'].value_counts(dropna = False)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Arch\Work\Register\a_Code\Snippets\i2b2test_NA_SO_Question.py in 
     18 
     19 
---> 20 df_i2b2['TBI_var'] = df_i2b2['DIAGNOSIS_CODES'].apply(diag_TBI)
     21 df_i2b2['TBI_var'].value_counts(dropna = False)
     22 

~\Anaconda3\envs\lake_reg2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

c:\Arch\Work\Register\a_Code\Snippets\i2b2test_NA_SO_Question.py in diag_TBI(my_str)
     11 
     12 def diag_TBI(my_str):
---> 13     if my_str.isna():
     14         return np.nan
     15     else:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isna'
```

**Question:** How to check for `np.nan` that is in data frame inside function that is applied to it? How to modify `if my_str.isna():`, to make code work?

Comment: `df['some_col'].isna()`?

Comment: @QuangHoang You mean use `df['some_col'].isna()` inside function? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although @CeliusStingher answer is the more appropriate way to do this.  Here's a trick you can use to check this NaN inside a function:

```
def diag_TBI(my_str):
    if my_str==my_str:
        return 1
    return np.nan

df_i2b2['DIAGNOSIS_CODES'].apply(diag_TBI)
```

Output:

```
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    NaN
Name: DIAGNOSIS_CODES, dtype: float64
```

***NOTE:*** In Python, NaN == NaN returns False.

Comment: I like your example very much! Just to clarify. `my_str==my_str` returns `False` only if `my_str=np.nan` and not in any other case, correct?

Comment: Yes.  `variable1 == variable1` will return True for any value other than NaN, then it returns False.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem easily in a vectorized way with `np.where()` without need of the `apply` function:

```
df_i2b2['TBI_var'] = np.where(df_i2b2['DIAGNOSIS_CODES'].isna(),np.nan,1)
```

This returns:

```
   id                          DIAGNOSIS_CODES  TBI_var
0   1  338.29; 353.6; 355.9; 722.6; 724.2; E43      1.0
1   2             278.00; 300.00; 305.1; 353.6      1.0
2   3         E66.9; F32.9; F41.9; J96.10; S06      1.0
3   4                                      NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def diag_TBI(my_str):
    if my_str == "nan":
        return np.nan
    return 1
```